# Converting stored MongoDB collection documents from BsonDocument to "MyClass" type?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following situation. I have two classes `Person` and `Animal`

```
using System;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
namespace MongoTesting.Documents
{
    public class Person
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        public Guid PersonId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

        public Guid PetId { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;

        public string Name { get; set; } = "Person";
    }
}

using System;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
namespace MongoTesting.Documents
{
    public class Animal
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        public Guid AnimalId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

        public bool IsMammal { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; } = "Animal";
    }
}
```

Which were serialized into `IMongoCollection`s

```
public IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> PersonCollection { get; set; }
public IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> AnimalCollection { get; set; }
...
PersonCollection = Database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("PersonCollection");
AnimalCollection = Database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("AnimalCollection");
```

In these collections of type `IMongoCollection<BsonDocument>` I now have a large amount of documents.

---

I recently have been refactoring my code and queries related to MongoDB. I have found that I can save documents into collections with strongly typed documents, for example I now have the collections

```
public IMongoCollection<Person> PersonCollection { get; set; }
public IMongoCollection<Animal> AnimalCollection { get; set; }
```

On which I can perform cleaner and more meaningful queries easily.

---

As result of these changes and the large amount of documents already stored in my collection I would like to convert the documents in the collection from `BsonDocument` to `Person`/`Animal` documents.

**How can I convert stored MongoDB collection documents from `BsonDocument` to documents of a specific class' type?**

---

Comment: Out of curiosity, what have you tried?

Comment: I am still searching, but my efforts seem in vain. Either this is not an issue that has been brought up before or there is some verbage that I cannot match to find information on it. I just keep finding posts about "convert BsonDocument to strong type". Which is worded closely but not the same question.

Comment: I'd need to write up a test case to confirm, but so long as the BsonDocument mirrors the properties of the type being mapped, the C# driver should take care of it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having just tested this, I can confirm that as long as the property names match, the C# driver will take care of the mapping by default. More complicated situations (like polymorphism) need a little more work, but in essence, you can do this:

```
//define the collection and a sample BsonDocument:
var collectionName = "bsonDocs";
var bsonDoc = BsonDocument.Parse("{ \"_id\" : ObjectId(\"5b476c4b7d1c1647b06f8e75\"), \"Detail\" : \"testString1\", }");
//Establish connection to database
var clientInstance = new MongoClient();
var db = clientInstance.GetDatabase("TEST");
//Get the collection as BsonDocuments
var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionName);
//Insert a BsonDocument
collection.InsertOne(bsonDoc);
//Get the same collection, this time as your data model type
var modelCollection = db.GetCollection<TestDataModel>(collectionName);
//Query that collection for your data models
var models = modelCollection.AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault();
//Write data models to that same collection
modelCollection.InsertOne(new TestDataModel{Detail = "new Item"});
```

where TestDataModel is:

```
class TestDataModel
{
    public ObjectId {get;set;}
    public string Detail {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: You are correct. Though I just realized I should have never asked this question. I had tried this solution many times with no result. It is now that I realize I had never restarted my mongod instance to reload a new database with the documents I wished to test on. This solution now works.